# How to put an image slider below webview content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-imageview, android-view

I am using custom view pager to show multiple images as slider. It works normal but it load image about one second before webview content loads (while webview content is empty) then moves below in layout. How can I avoid to load images inside empty webview content? I've searched through stackoverflow but couldn't find appropriate answer.

main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clickable="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/newsPageToolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/newsPageToolbar"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/newsTitleSinglePage"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/publishDateSinglePage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageSinglePage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="230dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/newsSourceSinglePage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/newsBody"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></WebView>

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/videoView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></WebView>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <com.eastnews.huseyn.eastnews.WrapContentViewPager
                                android:id="@+id/imagePager"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
                            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                                android:id="@+id/imageIndicator"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="48dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/newsLink"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/link" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

image layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter Class onMeasure method

```
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

    if(wrapHeight) {
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        if(getChildCount() > 0) {
            View firstChild = getChildAt(0);

            firstChild.measure(widthMeasureSpec,MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            height = firstChild.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved problem using visibility gone and visible. First, set visibility gone inside layout xml. Then use webview  `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){...}` function make view visible.